# Python Pandas - Groupby and Mean, but keep column name

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find the mean of a column for each unique value in another column, and am using the code:

```
A_df = B.groupby('R')['L'].mean
```

And I get the mean value for each value in 'R', but the mean values has no column name, so I cant sort on it.

Is there a way of doing what the above does, but give the mean values a column name so I can sort on it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter `as_index=False` or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
A_df = B.groupby('R', as_index=False)['L'].mean()
```

Or:

```
A_df = B.groupby('R')['L'].mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: Wow, that is super quick. Thank you VERY much, and have a good weekend! :)...... it worked and ill mark your answer as the right one as soon as it allows me.

Comment: Not sure if you will still see this message, but the index on the left hand side is in a weird order 11,2,8,7, 5 etc....  is there any way of removing this column or changing the index?

Comment: Then need add `.reset_index(drop=True)`